# Remove com port using devcon for loop

Tags: automation, windows-command-prompt, command

I started learning command line yesterday. My supervisor asked me to delete extra com ports.

I was trying to delete com port using command line. Right now I am using `devcon.exe` that is a part of windows WDK. I have tried using `devcon findall =ports` and used `devcon remove "@some specific id"`. It worked totally well.

so I start to create a for loop of command line using the following query

```
for /f %%i in ('devcon findall %1') do (devcon remove "@%%i")
```

But, It does not work. Would someone help me with that? Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: it seems like i accidentally delete your comment. So sorry!! Do I need to add * to the query? like 'for /f %%i in ('devcon findall **%1**') do (devcon remove "@%%i")'

Comment: @jscott   
Sorry to bother you again. To remove all com ports, I rewrite the batch file like the following:
for /f %%i in ('devcon findall =ports') do (devcon remove "@%%i")